# Get version string from argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to get back the version string I defined in `argparse` for use in logging.
I'm using a typical setup along the lines of:

```
__version__ = "0.1"
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--version', '-V', action='version', version="%(prog)s " + __version__)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I print `parser.version()` or `parser.print_version()` or `parser.format_version()` I get `None`. One solution is to call `parser.parse_args(['-V'])` but that also terminates the execution of the program. I know I can just re-create the string and pass it to the logger, but I thought there must be a way to get this from `argparse`. I'm using python v2.7.5 and argparse v1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format_version` (and `print_version` which uses `format_version`) displays the `parser.version` attribute, which you can set with the `version` parameter.  But as Martijn wrote, that approach to showing a version is depricated.  You'll get a warning message.

That `action='version'` argument takes a different route.  It has its own `version` parameter (but using `parser.version` as a backup).  When triggered by the `-v` argument string, it displays that version info and calls system exit.

You could still call `-v`, and avoid the system exit with a try block:

```
try:
    p.parse_args(['-V'])
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

That's handy for testing, but not something you want in production.  Plus it traps other exits like help and errors.

As with any argument, you can save a link to the Action, and display, use, or even modify its attributes.

```
version_action = parser.add_argument('--version', '-V', action='version', 
    version="%(prog)s " + __version__)
print version_action
print version_action.version
assert isinstance(version_action, argparse._VersionAction)
```

Functionally this is the same as Martijn's search of the `parser._get_optional_actions()`, but simpler.

You could replicate the action of the `_VersionAction.__call__`, without the system exit, with:

```
def foo(action, parser):
    formatter = parser._get_formatter()
    formatter.add_text(action.version)
    return formatter.format_help()
foo(version_action, parser)
```

Though in this case all it does is fill in the `%(prog)s` string.

http://bugs.python.org/issue9399 'Provide a 'print' action for argparse', discusses adding a 'print' or 'write' action type.  It would behave like the 'version' one, but without the system exit, and possibly more control over formatting and print destination.

Answer (score 3):

There is no *public* API to get that information. The `parser.version` attribute is deprecated. You'd have to find the `argparse._VersionAction` object and get it from there:

```
version_action = next((action for action in parser._get_optional_actions()
                       if isinstance(action, argparse._VersionAction)), None)
print version_action.version if version_action else 'unknown'
```

This uses private methods that are subject to change, and all you get is the *exact same string you gave to `argparse`*:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--version', '-V', action='version', version="%(prog)s " + __version__)
_VersionAction(option_strings=['--version', '-V'], dest='version', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help="show program's version number and exit", metavar=None)
>>> version_action = next((action for action in parser._get_optional_actions() if isinstance(action, argparse._VersionAction)), None)
>>> print version_action.version if version_action else 'unknown'
%(prog)s 0.1
```

Much easier just to store that value somewhere else too, then pass it to `argparse` *and* use the value directly.

Answer (score 0):

No, there must not be a way to get it from argparse. Why would there be? You tell argparse what the version number is, not the other way around.
And you don't need to "recreate" the string. Just create it once, and then pass it into argparse.

I'm sure it's available somehow, from some attribute on argparse, but getting it from there really makes no sense, and requires you to use argparse internals, which may change in the future.